# A doubt on the Bayesian/Frequentist approach to Probability Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I fail to understand a fact in the ever intriguing Bayesian/Frequentist discussion on Probability Theory.

While I strive to improve my yet rudimental understanding, I am still only a beginner in the field.

I will clarify my doubts with an example.
I toss a (possibly biased) coin $n$ times and it always comes “heads”. 
The naïve estimate is that the chance of getting heads on a single toss equals $1$.
As a frequentist, I could expand further by making the following claim
$$ P(n) = p^{n} $$
where $P(k)$ stands for the probability of $k$ heads in $n$ throws, and $p$ is the heads probability on a single trial.

I can also interpret the statement as telling me that the chances of heads on a single trial equals $$ p = P^{1/n} = (1- CL) ^{1/n} $$  where $CL$ stands for confidence level.
In other words, at say 95% confidence level, I accept events with probability $P > 0.05$.

I could  then  select a certain confidence level, and get an estimate $p_{CL} = (1- CL) ^{1/n}  $ for the probability of getting heads on a single trial.

If I followed the Bayesian approach it would seem at first  natural to assume a uniform prior, as the Frequentist did not make any claim on the prior.

I would obtain a density distribution $f(p)$ by evaluating the expression
$$f(p) = \frac{p^n}{\int_0^1 p^n \mathrm{d}p} = (n+1) p^n$$

Now I cannot avoid being tempted to reconnect to the frequentist view, and argue that I could get an estimate for $p_{CL}$ at a given $CL$ by calculating
$$\int_{p_{CL}}^1 (n+1) s^{n} \mathrm{d}s = CL$$ giving $$p_{CL}= (1 – CL)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} $$

In words, I am computing the lower bound on the $p$ value, such that the range $[p;1]$  covers CL % of the cases, as done, I believe, in the frequentist approach.

The expression are similar, but the exponent differs being $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ I for the frequentist and Bayesian cases respectively. At least, they converge for $n \to \infty$.

So what is going wrong? I am reading all I can but have so far failed to pinpoint the source of the inconsistency (if there is one at all, i.e. if I am not overlooking some difference in the approaches making the above nonsensical).

Comment: The Bayesian approach does not require you to assume a uniform prior! You can assume whatever prior accounts for all of the prior knowledge you in fact have, including a prior that places positive probability on $p = 1$ (sometimes coins in fact have heads on both sides), or the Jeffreys prior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, thanks for your comment. I understand what you mean, but yet I am trying to reconcile the two approaches here. As the Frequentist does not make any claim on the prior, would it not the most coherent choice be for the Bayesian to assume a uniform prior? I realise things might be subtler, but cannot put my finger on why.

Comment: I'm finding lots of things in your question unclear, and in particular you seem to to be adhering to the standard meaning of terms such as "confidence level", and I also can't tell how you got $(1-CL)^{1/n}$ or $(1-CL)^{1/(n+1)}.$ But despite these uncertainties, it seems unlikely that you've shown that anything is going wrong.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, I hope I did not give the impression I am claiming to have found some paradox or inconsistency in the theory: far from that, I believe the inconsistency stems from one or more mistakes of mine. If you could be more specific on what is unclear in the derivations I would gladly expand upon them. The first one should be pretty standard, via the binomial distribution: the second one is obtained by integrating over the density I calculated via Bayes's Theorem.

Comment: You say you "believe the inconsistency stems from one or more mistakes of mine", but it's not clear which "inconsistency" you're referring to.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, thank you for your socratic approach. I eventually understood that actually, there is no inconsistence at all!